# Control Initialization Order Fiasco

Tags: wpf, events, initialization, initialization-order

Consider the following code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged/>
        <TextBox x:Name="counter"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

        void slider_ValueChanged(object sender,
            RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            counter.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Slider will raise its `ValueChanged` event *during* initialization while `counter` is still `null`.

This is an example of a larger problem that I've been running into using WPF, that UI events can fire at any time, and that there is no single place where I can put my initialization code so that it's guaranteed to run after all the pointers owned by the WPF system have been initialized but before any UI events have fired.

**What is the most elegant way to deal with this?** The fact that this specific example should use data binding is beside the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *true* answer to this question is to use the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern where window code behind files contain little to no initialization code.

In this pattern, the UI is connected to the rest of the code with data binding only. You write special view-model classes that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and take your business logic and expose it as a series of properties that UI binds to.

Naturally, you fully control how your view-models initialize.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to deal with this, depending on your situation

First off, you could simply recognize the fact that the object might not be initialized and check for that before processing. For example,

```
if (counter.Text != null)
    counter.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
```

Second, you could attach your events in the Loaded event of the object so they don't fire until after the object has been initialized.

```
void Counter_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    slider.ValueChanged += Slider_ValueChanged;
}

void Counter_Unloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    slider.ValueChanged -= Slider_ValueChanged;
}
```

And last of all, you can use WPF's [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) to run events on the UI thread at a different [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx). The default is `Normal`, which runs after `Loaded`, `Render`, and `DataBind` operations

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, 
    new Action(delegate() { counter.Text = e.NewValue.ToString(); }));
```